# Set model field default value set based on previous object's value from model class

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I set model managers to query the request_number of the last record in the database. The default value of the request number should be 210001 (if the first record of the year 2021), or the next sequential number of the current year (20002, 20003, 20004, etc).

How do I set the code to look at the previous record as part of setting the default value of the model field?

```
from django.db import models
import datetime


class ServiceRequestManager(models.Manager):

    def last_record(self):
        last_record_year = int(self.last().request_number[0:2])
        return last_record_year

    def last_record_request_number_plus_one(self):
        last_request_number = int(self.last().request_number) + 1
        return last_request_number

    def test(self):
        year_difference = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%y')) - int(self.last().request_number[0:2])
        return year_difference


def number():
    year = str(datetime.date.today().strftime('%y'))  # Pulls last two digits of the year
    # previous_record_year = ServiceRequestManager.last_record
    # new_request_number = ServiceRequestManager.last_record_request_number_plus_one
    # current_record_year = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%y'))
    if int(year) > ServiceRequestManager.last_record(): # TypeError: last_record() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
        return year
    else:
        i = 1
        i_pad = "%04d" % i  # creates 000x so default is 0001
        return year+str(i_pad)  # Creates the full request number e.g. 200001

# Need the next record to be 200002, 200003, 200004 etc until the first instance of 2021 which would be 210001, 210002, etc.


# Create your models here.
class ServiceRequest(models.Model):

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (None, ''),
        ('aircraft_repair', 'Aircraft Repair'),
        ('backshop', 'Backshop'),
        ('documentation', 'Documentation'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    )

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (None, ''),
        ('1', '1-Critical (<24 hours)'),
        ('2', '2-Urgent (1-2 Days)'),
        ('3', '3-Standard (3 Days)'),
        ('4', '4-Low (5 Days)')
    )

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    request_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=number())

    objects = ServiceRequestManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.request_number # show the request number in admin screen

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-request_number',) # sort request number descending in admin screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a function that looks for the `ServiceRequest` that starts with the first two digits of the year, and then look for the last one of these records.

If no such record exists, we return `f'{y2}0000'` (so we "start" a new sequence), and if it does, we parse it to an `int`, then increment it, and obtain the last four digits to create a new one:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def number():
    y2 = now().strftime('%y')
    last_request = ServiceRequest.objects.filter(
        request_number__startswith=y2
    ).order_by('-request_number').values_list('request_number', flat=True).first()
    if last_request is None:
        return f'{y2}0000'
    else:
        num = (int(last_request) + 1) % 10000
        return f'{y2}{num:04d}'
```

In the model, we pass `default=number`, so a *reference* to the function, not the *result* of *calling* the function. Furthermore it might be useful to specify a database index, and make the field unique (to prevent generating two records with the same `reference_number` in the database):

```
class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (None, ''),
        ('aircraft_repair', 'Aircraft Repair'),
        ('backshop', 'Backshop'),
        ('documentation', 'Documentation'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    )

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (None, ''),
        ('1', '1-Critical (<24 hours)'),
        ('2', '2-Urgent (1-2 Days)'),
        ('3', '3-Standard (3 Days)'),
        ('4', '4-Low (5 Days)')
    )

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    request_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        db_index=True,
        default=number,
        unique=True
    )
```

Perhaps four digits is however not enough. It might be more safe to use `max_length=8` for example, to allow 1'000'000 request numbers per year. Especially since some request numbers are perhaps not valid (and will thus be closed).

Comment: Willem - Thank you for the quick response. I implemented your suggested code and received the following error (updated above). Any suggestions? Side note: I just recently began learning python and this is my first big project. Please forgive me if I happen to use the wrong terminology.

Comment: I can't seem to get the terminal lines of code to load. But, the final line says   File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
esr_submit.models.ServiceRequest.DoesNotExist: ServiceRequest matching query does not exist.

Comment: @JustLearning123: sorry, made a mistake. Updated.

Comment: No worries. Changes made. Threw the following error. Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value: 
Cannot resolve keyword '-request_number' into field. Choices are: EgItem, EgWorkOrder, EgZone, NrcItem, NrcWorkOrder, NrcZone, aircraft, category, contact, description, email, first_name, id, last_name, priority, references, request_number, timestamp, updated

Comment: If I change the keyword to 'request_number', the next error thrown says:  ```int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'``` for the following line ```num = (int(last_request) + 1) % 10000```

Comment: @JustLearning123: but you did this in an `.order_by(..)`? Not `.values(..)` or `.filter(...)` or anything?

Comment: I don't 100% understand your question. I followed your prescribed code including the respective edits made. I don't know if you noticed, but I had previously created 3 custom model managers at the beginning of my models.py file. Could those be causing problems? Could my Meta class be causing issues?

Comment: @JustLearning123: no the manager will not cause the problem. Are you sure you copied the `def number` function exactly as in the answer. Can you edit the question and show your implementation of `number`?

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. Operator error...Thanks so much! I am going form 0-60 on learning programming. I love it, but a lot to learn. So thankful for a helpful community! Have a good day!

Comment: Can this same action be accomplished in the view when the user clicks the submit button to post the form data to the server?

Comment: @JustLearning123: normally it will, but if you want to make the field non-editable, you set `editable=False`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable

Comment: I decided to keep it in the model. If two users open the request form prior to the first submitting, they will have the same request number which will throw the "Service request with this Request number already exists." How do I check for this error on submit and add 1 to the number if the error occurs?

Comment: @JustLearning123: can you ask a new question and add the code of the view?